# How to concatenate two TF-IDF Vectors as well as other features that can be fed into a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, tf-idf

**The solution I found that works in my case is posted below. Hope this helps someone.**
How would I concatenate the output of TF-IDF created with sklearn to be passed into a Keras model or tensor that could then be fed into a dense neural network? I'm working on the FakeNewsChallenge dataset. Any guidance would be helpful.

The FakeNewsChallenge dataset is as such:

Training Set - [Headline, Body text, label]

- Training Set is split into two different CSVs (train_bodies, train_stances) and are linked by BodyIDs.
- train_bodies - [Body ID (num), articleBody (text)]
- train_stances - [Headline (text), Body ID (num), Stance (text)]

Test Set - [Headline, Bodytext]

- Test set is split into two different CSVs (test_stances_inlabled, test_bodies]
- Test_bodies - [Body ID, aritcleBody]
- Test_stances_unlabled - [Headline, Body ID]

Distribution makes it extremely hard:

- rows - 49972
- unrelated - 0.73131
- discuss - 0.17828
- agree - 0.076012
- disagree - 0.0168094

Stance - [ unrelated, discuss, agree, disagree]

---

What I would like to do is concatenate two separate TF-IDF Vectors as well as other features that I can then feed into a some layer for instance a dense layer. How would you go about that? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a comment prior to mine that answered the question but I do not see the comment anymore. I apparently forgot about this method, but was using it in other areas of my program.

You use the numpy.hstack(tup) or numpy.vstack(tup), where

- tup - sequence of ndarrays

  The arrays must have the same shape along all but the second axis, except 1-D arrays which can be any length.

It returns a stacked: ndarray.

Here is some code just incase.

Note: I do not have cosine similarity calculation here. Do that however you want. I'm trying to do this fast but also as clear as possible. Hope this helps someone.

---

```
def computeTF_IDF(trainX1, trainX2, testX1, testX2):
 vectorX1 = TfidfVectorizer(....)
 tfidfX1 = vectorX1.fit_Trasnsform(trainX1)

 vectorX2 = TfidfVectorizer(....)
 tfidfX2 = vectorX2.fit_Trasnsform(trainX2)

 tfidf_testX1= vec_body.transform(testX1)
 tfidf_testX2 = vec_headline.transform(testX2)
 
 # Optionally, you can insert code from * to ** here from below.

 return vectorX1, tfidfX1, ... , tfidf_testX1, tfidf_testX2

# Call TF-IDF function to compute.
trainX1_tfidf, trainX2_tfidf, testX1_tfidf , testX2_tfidf = computeTFIDF(trainX1,...,testX2)

#*

# Stack matrices horizontally (column wise) using hstack().
trainX_tfidf = scipy.sparse.hstack([trainX1_tfidf, trainX2_tfidf])
testX_tfidf = scipy.sparse.hstack([testX1_tfidf, testX2_tfidf])

# Convert Spare Matrix into an Array using toarray() 
trainX_tfidf_arr = trainX_tfidf.toarray()
testX_tfidf_arr = testX_tfidf.toarray()

# Concatenate TF-IDF and Cosine Similarity using numpy.c_[], 
# which is just another column stack.
trainX_tfidf_cos = np.c_[trainX_tfidf_arr, cosine_similarity]
testX_tfidf_cos = np.c_[testX_tfidf_arr, cosine_similarity_test]

#**

# You can now pass this to your Keras model.
```